# Novel with a paid assassin who travels with a variety of older companions

Tags: story-identification, books

The book starts off with a guy who was hired to kill a royal family member. He travels through a tunnel under a wall, with an old man he met with a bird (parrot?), to arrive where the procession was going to be traversing across a planet.

Later he travels with an old women on a spaceship, who was someone he knew when she was young (but he doesn't realize it). The guy ends up on a prison planet and manages to escape again with the help of the old man and the bird. There is more, but that should be enough to identify it, I hope.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. Also, if you know more info than you've put down, you should absolutely edit that in.

Answer (score 6):

This is [*Star Bridge* by James Gunn and Jack Williamson](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B089RR2GXS) (1955; from a 1942 story by Williamson titled *Breakdown*).

The adventurer, Horn, must not assassinate a royal family member, but Garth Kolnar, one of the highest-level managers of the Eron Company.

I stopped reading the book shortly after the assassination scene and subsequent escape, so can't confirm the rest, but I can vouch for the old man and the parrot (which is actually a shapeshifting alien). This is the scene of their meeting:

> Horn glanced at the suitcase beside the man's feet. There was
> lettering on the side; it was scratched, faded, and archaic, like the
> old man's speech. It said: *Mr. Oliver Wu, Proprietor, New Canton
> Sanitary Laundry*. Horn took four quick strides to the right. On the
> other side, he read: *Lily. The Mathematical Parrot. Can Do Sums.*
>
> - Poor China boy will get himself killed quick with a fire on the Forbidden Ground, - Horn said deliberately. - A hunting party of the
> Golden Folk trailed me to within half a kilometer of this spot.
>
> Wu's face got paler. His legs gave way under him. He sank down in
> front of the boulder. The parrot settled on his shoulder, staring at
> Horn with her one good eye.
>
> - Poor li'l China boy, - Wu said shakily. - No gottee nothing. One stupid bird. - He cringed as the bird bit his ear. - One dirty
> clothes. - His patched, outsize boot kicked the battered suitcase. - No makee tlouble noblody.
>
> - The hunters will kill you just as quick, - Horn said casually. - They're gone now, but they'll be back. If we're still here.... - He
> let it hang in the air, unfinished.
>
> - No one talks well, - the parrot said, - with gun in face.
>
> Horn laughed, mirthlessly, and dropped the gun.